# XML to dictionary extraction

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, extract

I wrote a code and some values at ecd are missing. I would like to indicate them as `'None'` or `0000` to be able to create a dataframe. Unfortunately, the code runs until the missing place and then it crashes and I cannot spot a mistake.

The error message:

```
File "extra.py", line 236, in <module>
    if dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'][i]['ecdTdAv']['#text'] != None:
  KeyError: 'ecdTdAv'
```

Code:

```
xml_file = 'C:\\Users\\jtfra\\Desktop\\Thesis\\Volve_Real_Time_DData\\WITSML Realtime drilling data\\Norway-Statoil-NO 15_$47$_9-F-11\\1\\mudLog\\1.xml'

def convert(xml_file, xml_attribs=True):
with open(xml_file, "rb") as f:    # notice the "rb" mode
    d = xmltodict.parse(f, xml_attribs=xml_attribs)
    return d

dic = convert(xml_file)
mdTop, ecd = [], []


 for i in range(len(dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'])):
    mdTop.append(dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'][i]['mdTop']['#text'])

    if dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'][i]['ecdTdAv']['#text'] != None:
        ecd.append(dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'][i]['ecdTdAv']['#text'])
    else:
        ecd.append('None')

print(ecd)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of accessing it as:

```
dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'][0]['ecdTdAv']
```

do:

```
dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'][0].get('ecdTdAv', '0000')
```

or similar.

You can also check if key is present with:

```
if 'ecdTdAv' in dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'][I]:
    # do something with it, e.g.:
    print(dic['mudLogs']['mudLog']['geologyInterval'][i]['ecdTdAv']['#text'])
```